# how to get the ip address of the client from server side in next.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I want to get the user time zone and location to render a server-side page depending on the location and time zone but I can't get the user IP address from the request or get the localhost IP address (127.0.0.1). so what should I do ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use something like [request-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) package. Then in your API route:

```
import requestIp from 'request-ip'

export default async function myRoute(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const detectedIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req)
}
```

Comment: this package give me a wrong ip address as the location of the IP address is wrong

Comment: What do you mean the ip address is wrong? It will report the IP address extracted from the headers, it even looks for `x-forwarded-for` proxy header

Comment: it gives me an ip address different from my IP address is there any config i should put on nginx to pass these headers ?

Comment: it works now with this solution but there are some config should be added to nginx.config to  pass request headers.

Comment: this one is giving me azure's page host Ip address... @mohamed can you tell me which configs did you have to add?

Answer (score 22):

Was able to detect user IP address with next.js app:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  const forwarded = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]
  const ip = forwarded ? forwarded.split(/, /)[0] : req.connection.remoteAddress
  return {
    props: {
      ip,
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me!

Comment: This approach is potentially insecure; X-Forwarded-For can be spoofed and should only be accepted if it comes from a trusted proxy.

Comment: Note that req.connection is deprecated as of Next.js 13. Use req.socket.remoteAddress instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the NextRequest object as a direct replacement for the native Request interface, giving you more control over how you manipulate the request.
Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request

NextRequest is fully typed and can be imported from next/server.

```
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
```

The NextRequest object is an extension of the native Request interface, with the following added methods and properties:

1. cookies - Has the cookies from the Request
2. nextUrl - Includes an extended, parsed, URL object that gives you
   access to Next.js specific properties such as pathname, basePath,
   trailingSlash and i18n
3. geo - Has the geo location from the Request
4. geo.country - The country code
5. geo.region - The region code
6. geo.city - The city
7. geo.latitude - The latitude
8. geo.longitude - The longitude
9. ip - Has the IP address of the Request
10. ua - Has the user agent

Comment: Note that `next/server` is only available in Next.js 12+ https://blog.logrocket.com/whats-new-next-js-12/

Comment: How do I use this? I'm struggling to implement it

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro Also note that `NextRequest` is only available on the [`Edge Runtime`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime). It won't work on regular API routes or Node.js server-side code.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77791867/654070

Answer (score 5):

You can also try using page's `getInitialProps`.

```js
IndexPage.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const ip = req.headers["x-real-ip"] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
  return { ip };
};
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-sun-broko?file=/pages/index.js)

Comment: it gives me  (127.0.0.1) also. is there any configuration should I use in Nginx to pass any headers to the request ?

Comment: In Google cloud run, this doesn't give the right IP. It gives internal load balancer's IP.

Comment: this solution gives me the private Ip, not the public Ip :(

Answer (score 2):

**Create an API page/route: /api/get-ip-address**,
under /pages/api folder, create get-ip-address.ts file and add this content.

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  let ipAddress = req.headers["x-real-ip"] as string;

  const forwardedFor = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] as string;
  if (!ipAddress && forwardedFor) {
    ipAddress = forwardedFor?.split(",").at(0) ?? "Unknown";
  }

  res.status(200).json(ipAddress);
};

export default handler;
```

**On your page file**, fetch (GET method) the above endpoint (/api/get-ip-address) using Axios or Fetch API inside a useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when the user sends a request in NextJS the request contains a socket instance that has properties, this can be the remote IP address, and remote port and other useful information.

So for anyone looking for exactly how to get this IP address of the connection remote end, you can do something like this

```
Login.getInitialProps = async ({ req, res }: any) => {
  const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress
  // and use some other api to get location like country from the ip address
  return { ip }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the app router you can't access the NextRequest in server code, but you can use `middleware.ts` to add new request headers that you can access is server side code.

Regarding IP address, it's worth noting this from [Vercel](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request#ip)

> The ip property is a string that contains the IP address of the
> request. This value can optionally be provided by your hosting
> platform. Good to know: On Vercel , this value is provided by default.
> On other platforms, you can use the X-Forwarded-For header to provide
> the IP address.

```
function middleware(req) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers)

  // Add new request headers
  requestHeaders.set('request-ip', req.ip);
  requestHeaders.set('request-url', req.url);
  requestHeaders.set('request-geo', JSON.stringify(req.geo));

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  })
}
```

Then server side:

```
  import {headers} from "next/headers";

  const headersList = headers()
  const ip = headersList.get('request-ip')
```