# How to write a middleware in nextjs for serverside

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I need a middleware in my nextjs project which is a monorepo (frontend and backend in the same project) and I need to intercept the requests through a middleware and do the stuff I basically do in every API: authentication and other controls. I took a look [to this](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware)  but I can't figue out how to get the actual request (headers, body, query string etc).

So I created the file `_middleware.ts` under the `/pages` folder and this:

```
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
  console.log('request - - -- - >', req);
}
```

I thought in `req` parameter I had the entire request but I didn't. In fact, if I log it I get this result:

```
NextRequestHint [Request] {
  sourcePage: '/_middleware',
  [Symbol(internal body)]: { bodyInit: null, disturbed: false },
  [Symbol(internal request)]: {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: BaseHeaders [Headers] { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] },
    method: 'GET',
    referrer: 'about:client',
    redirect: 'follow',
    url: NextURL { [Symbol(NextURLInternal)]: [Object] }
  },
  [Symbol(internal request)]: {
    cookieParser: [Function: cookieParser],
    geo: {},
    ip: undefined,
    page: { name: '/[user]', params: [Object] },
    url: NextURL { [Symbol(NextURLInternal)]: [Object] }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the entire request here? Or is there another way in doing a middleware where I can do the general things I do for every API? thank you.

**version nextjs:** `12.0.9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NextRequest` class extends a `Request` interface which is based on [its native counterpart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request). You can see the different properties available to you in the following files:

- `node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js`
- `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`

Accessing them would look something like this:

```
// pages/api/_middleware.ts
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const streamToString = async (stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null) => {
  if (stream) {
    const chunks = [];
    for await (const chunk of stream) {
      chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk));
    }
    return Buffer.concat(chunks).toString("utf-8");
  }
  return null;
};

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
  console.log("Method:", req.method);
  console.log("Content-Type:", req.headers.get("content-type"));
  console.log("Route:", req.nextUrl.pathname);
  console.log("Query String:", req.nextUrl.search);
  console.log("Query Parameters:", req.nextUrl.searchParams);
  console.log("Body:", await streamToString(req.body));

  // do your stuff on the `Request`

  const res = NextResponse.next();

  // do your stuff on the `Response`

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Looking at your example and the referenced Request docs, am I correct in concluding that there is no way to access the end users IP address in middleware?

Comment: @user5801710 `ip` is one of the properties that `NextRequest` adds and it's [documented here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server#nextrequest).

Comment: Thanks Mark, appreciate your help.
I actually already tried accessing it this way earlier and got undefined (on dev/localhost), but based on your comment I tried deploying it to Vercel and here it works like a charm.

Comment: is it possible to get it on api, server side? ('pages/api/_middleware.tsx')

Comment: @BrunoYuzo See if [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68338838/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-client-from-server-side-in-next-js-app) helps.

Comment: With this code, it's returning the error: "You're using a Node.js module (buffer) which is not supported in the Edge Runtime."

Comment: @BrunoYuzo To avoid extended discussion in this comment section (and I can't tell if your issue is related to the original question/answer), [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead and reference any relevant threads if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since some months ago, the use of nested `_middleware.ts` files is deprecated in favor of a single `middleware.ts` file located in the root project directory.

You can find out more information in the following links:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/36772

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/nested-middleware

Regards,