# Stripe webhook security - verify IP address in addition to signature?

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm using webhooks in a `Next.js` app to handle incoming customer payment events from Stripe. Similar to the [example](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#verify-official-libraries) in the docs, the first thing my webhook does is verify the signature of the incoming event:

```
const webhookSecret = process.env.SECRET_STRIPE_WEBHOOK

const webhookHandler = async (req, res) =>
{
  if (req.method === 'POST')
  {  
    const buf = await buffer(req)
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']

    let event

    try
    {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf.toString(), sig, webhookSecret)
    }
    catch (error)
    {
      const errorMessage = error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error'
      // On error, log and return the error message
      if (error instanceof Error) console.log(error)
      console.log(`Error message: ${errorMessage}`)
      res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${errorMessage}`)
      return
    }

    // The rest of the webhook
  }
}
```

However, the docs also mention to [only trust events coming from these IP addresses](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#verify-events), and provides a [list](https://stripe.com/docs/ips#webhook-notifications) of IP addresses from which webhook events may originate.

For security purposes, is it necessary to also check the IP address of the incoming event, or does the above implementation of verifying the signature cover all bases? The docs explain that verifying signatures through Stripe's libraries does protect against [replay attacks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#replay-attacks), but they do still mention verifying IP addresses in the same sentence.

If verifying IP addresses is a necessary or prudent thing to do, how can I add that to the above implementation? I wasn't able to find examples on the Stripe docs.

Answer (score 1):

Verifying the IP address is an additional layer of security to guarantee the request comes from Stripe. Years ago it was the best approach as webhook signatures didn't exist but since they shipped this feature I think most developers have defaulted to that approach. An attacker can't calculate the signature themselves though they could find a way to replay the requests. I would say most integrations do not bother with the IP allow list.

If you were to implement this, you'd need to look at the IP address associated with the request in your route server-side. This is done with [NextRequest](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server#nextrequest) though there are other solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68338838/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-client-from-server-side-in-next-js-app).