# How to redirect cookie and user ip address in server side network request in nextjs?

Tags: cookies, next.js, ip, server-side-rendering

I am new to nextjs and SSR in general. I have previously worked through CSR in ReactJS. If a react application makes a request to the server API, then the server receives the cookie and the client's IP address.
But in the case of SSR, if NextJS makes a request on the server side, then the backend sees the IP address of the server where NextJS is located.
In this case, how can the backend server recognize the IP address of the client, and not the NextJS server? And how to send client cookies to the backend?
I need to know the client's IP to avoid cheating product ratings by guests.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [how to get the ip address of the client from server side in next.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68338838/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-client-from-server-side-in-next-js-app)? You can then forward the IP in your server-side requests.

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you. And how then to forward the received IP further in the request?

Comment: You could, for instance, pass it as an header in the request to the API.