# Next js API send server ip instead of client ip

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Hello there i'm using nodejs as microservice for auth multiple apps (mobile web ....)
and there is an app with nextjs that i am fetching the api in API routes

now i managed setting up the cookies and user agent but for the client ip still getting server ip

- Login code

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
      const params = await request.json();
      const userAgent = request.headers.get('user-agent') || ""
      const addressIp = (request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for') || "").split(',').pop()?.trim() || "" //(request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for') || '').split(',').pop().trim() || ""

      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_HOST}/auth/register`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "User-Agent": userAgent,
          "X-Forwarded-For": addressIp
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(params)
      });

      const data = await res.json()

      // get cookies and reset them
      const cookiesFromResponse = res.headers.get('set-cookie') || "";

      return NextResponse.json(data, { status: res.status, headers: { 'Set-Cookie': cookiesFromResponse } })
    }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68338838/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-client-from-server-side-in-next-js-app) answer your question?

Comment: the proble is i can get the client ip i created an api like /api/client-ip

Code 

`
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const ip = request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for') || "";

  return NextResponse.json({ ip });
}
`

i'm getting my client address ip 
i just want to know is there any way to set the client ip inside the request