# How to get client's ip address in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, ip-address, next.js13

I have a next.js 13 app and want to add an API endpoint `/api/getIP`.

The `route.js` file is in the `/app/api/getIP/route.js`.

Minimal Reproduceable Code:
https://github.com/Nusab19/nextjs-test/tree/main/app

I tried several ways of doing it but none of them worked. I tried using `request-ip` to get the ip but it returned `null`.

Here is my code:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import requestIp from "request-ip";

export async function GET(req) {
  const detectedIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req);
  const data = {
    ok: true,
    ip: detectedIp,
    userAgent: req.headers.get("user-agent"),
  };
  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}
```

I get this response when I visit:

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "ip": null,
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the ip address of the client from server side in next.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68338838/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-client-from-server-side-in-next-js-app)

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad No, I tried them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using Next.js `app` router, I'm assuming you are hosting on Vercel.

If yes, Vercel can provide these information by using a [Next.js Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware).

> ip: (string || undefined) - Has the IP address of the Request. This information is provided by your hosting platform.
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/next-server#nextrequest

You can create a Next.js `app` middleware by creating the file `middleware.js` at the root of your repo (if you are using `src/app`, then it should be `src/middleware.js`), with content:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const { ip, nextUrl } = req;

  nextUrl.searchParams.set('clientIp', ip);

  return NextResponse.rewrite(nextUrl);
}
```

The above code will add the `clientIp` as a query param and then pass it your route handler.

Within your route handler, you can access it like:

```js
export async function GET(req) {
  const data = {
    ok: true,
    ip: req.query?.clientIp ?? "127.0.0.1",
    message: "Hello from the API",
  };
  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}
```

The downside is that, it wont work in your local environment (you know your local ip anyway) and any hosting platforms that do not provide this information.

---

If you dont want to use a middleware, you can use the request headers to retrieve the ip.

```js
export async function GET(req) {
  const data = {
    ok: true,
    ip: req.headers.get("x-real-ip") ?? "127.0.0.1",
    message: "Hello from the API",
  };
  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}
```

Comment: It is hosted on vercel. But this implementation isn't working either. Here's the code: https://cutt.ly/Pwv9gaLk

Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: @NusabTaha-Nusab19 Because thats not how you create a middleware. I have updated my answer on how to create the middleware. Can you check if it works now?

Comment: @NusabTaha-Nusab19 Your `GET` route handler is also wrong. I have updated my answer to show how to the query param as well.

Comment: I get this error in `npm run build`.

Error occurred prerendering page "/api/user". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientIp')

Comment: @NusabTaha-Nusab19 You still haven't created the middleware. It needs to be inside `middleware.js` in the root. Please read my answer again.

Comment: Sorry for that. my bad, lemme fix it'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255435/discussion-between-nusab-taha-nusab19-and-robin-thomas).

Answer (score 3):

A shorter method that doesn't require using any third-party libraries or services.

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

/** @param {NextRequest} req */
export async function GET(req) {
  const { ua } = userAgent(req);

  const headersList = headers();
  const ip = headersList.get("x-forwarded-for");

  const data = {
    ok: true,
    ip_address: ip,
    user_agent: ua,
  };

  return NextResponse.json(data, { status: 200 });
}
```

Now, this code example answers your question.

Comment: this works too. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
const getIp = (request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for') ?? '127.0.0.1').trim().split(',')
const ipCheck =  getIp.length > 1 ? getIp[getIp.length - 1].trim() : getIp
const ip = request.ip ?? ipCheck
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**